If you hit Flowey after the Photoshop fight, does he die or does he just leave you alone because you gave him what he wanted?
If you hit Flowey after the Photoshop fight, does he die or does he just leave you alone because you gave him what he wanted?
The reason I'm asking is because attacking him in a Genocide Route, his face doesn't disappear after the first strike, but hitting him once in a Neutral Route turns him into (what appears to be) a regular flower.

I did write that, someone edited it

My original question was what happens after photochop flowery, which is the final boss of the first neutral run
